# What could be the work around for this following issue (specific to IE)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, cross-browser

In IE, when user uses Export To Excel (downloading .xls file) functionality in my SSL website, following error message is popping up:-

**Internet Explorer cannot download file from server........**

This is the exact definition of the issue here:-

> **CAUSE:** In order for Internet Explorer to open
>   documents in Office (or any
>   out-of-process, ActiveX document
>   server), Internet Explorer must save
>   the file to the local cache directory
>   and ask the associated application to
>   load the file by using
>   IPersistFile::Load. If the file is not
>   stored to disk, this operation fails. 
>   When Internet Explorer communicates
>   with a secure Web site through SSL,
>   Internet Explorer enforces any
>   no-cache request. If the header or
>   headers are present, Internet Explorer
>   does not cache the file. Consequently,
>   Office cannot open the file.
>   **RESOLUTION:** Web sites that want to
>   allow this type of operation should
>   remove the no-cache header or headers.

I cannot remove no-cache header from whole website(SSL). Can anybody suggest some work around here? Export to Excel functionality is only on one page of entire website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find any work around so far. 
Only solution, i found is to remove no-cache header from my SSL website.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Response.Headers.Clear()` before the server code the writes out the excel file does anything else.

Comment: Response.Clear(); This is I am already doing. is it same as Response.Headers.Clear()?